# В чем может быть причина undefined у offset().top?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, веб-программирование

господа.

Мастерю себе скрипт плавного перемещения по якорям на лендинге.

Написал такой код:

```
$('.anchor').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var height = document.body.offsetHeight;
    var curPos = $(document).scrollTop();

    //to the anchor
    var anchorID = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(anchorID);
    var anchorPos = $(anchorID).offset().top;
    console.log(anchorPos);
    var scrollTime = 0;

    if (anchorPos > curPos) {
      scrollTime = (height - curPos) / 3;
      $("body,html").animate({
        "scrollTop": anchorPos
      }, scrollTime);
    } else {
      scrollTime = curPos / 3;
      $("body,html").animate({
        "scrollTop": anchorPos
      }, scrollTime);
    }

  });
```

На лендинге есть 4 якоря такого вида:

```
<a name="test1"></a>
...
<a name="test2"></a>
...
<a name="test3"></a>
```

Ссылки, которые ведут на якоря выглядят вот так:

```
  <li>
    <a class="anchor" href="#test1">test1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="anchor" href="#test2">test2</a>
  </li>
```

Скрипт работает на с 1 и последней ссылках.
Те, что в середине, выбивают ошибку

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Не могу понять почему при 1 и последней все нормально, а при остальных ошибка

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He `name`, a `id`.

Выборка `$(anchorID)` не содержит DOM-элементов, и ее метод `.offset()` возвращает `undefined`.

```js
$('.anchor').bind('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var height = document.body.offsetHeight;
  var curPos = $(document).scrollTop();

  //to the anchor
  var anchorID = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log(anchorID);
  var anchorPos = $(anchorID).offset().top;
  console.log(anchorPos);
  var scrollTime = 0;

  if (anchorPos > curPos) {
    scrollTime = (height - curPos) / 3;
    $("body,html").animate({
      "scrollTop": anchorPos
    }, scrollTime);
  } else {
    scrollTime = curPos / 3;
    $("body,html").animate({
      "scrollTop": anchorPos
    }, scrollTime);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
На лендинге есть 4 якоря такого вида:

<a id="test1">111</a> ...
<a id="test2">222</a> ...
<a id="test3">333</a> ...
<a id="test4">444</a> Ссылки, которые ведут на якоря выглядят вот так:

<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="anchor" href="#test1">test1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="anchor" href="#test2">test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="anchor" href="#test3">test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="anchor" href="#test4">test4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Логика у меня отсутствует напрочь.
Действительно заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Вы ищете `id`, но тегам указали атрибут `name`.

Замените все `<a name="testX">` на `<div id="testX">`.

Comment: Спасибо!
Совет помог коду ожить